# Remove li and from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-lists

```
//Created based off other variables
array = ["apple", "john", "monkey"]; 

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var li=document.createElement('li');

    ul.appendChild(li);

    li.innerHTML += '<li>' + array[i];
    li.innerHTML += '<a href="#" class="clear">'+remove+'</a></li>';

}
$('a.clear').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();

    return false;
});
```

You can see from above (not complete code, but basic idea), that each created `li` has a "remove" button associated to it. Clicking on the "remove" will remove the `li`, but I cannot figure out how exactly to remove it from the array...

I attempted to add a value to the associated `li` like so:

```
   li.innerHTML += '<a href="#" value="'+array[i]+'" class="clear">'+remove+'</a></li>;
```

I was thinking maybe I can use the value when clicked on "remove" as function will match against the array using `indexOf` and remove it, but I couldn't figure out how exactly to pull any values from the click function.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array = ["apple", "john", "monkey"]; 

$( "body" ).append( "<ul></ul>" );

for(i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    $( "ul" ).append( $( "<li>" ).html(array[i]+' <a href="#" class="clear" data-item="'+array[i]+'">remove</a>' ));

}

$('a.clear').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
   $(this).parent().remove();
 index = array.indexOf($(this).data('item'));
if(index != -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
}

 console.log(array);
});
```

JQuery solution: http://jsfiddle.net/v9p5k6sm/2/

Explanation - it is safer to check value, not key, because keys are changed, after splicing.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is a lot more straight forward, by passing the data-item. Good thing I set up in my array that doesn't have identical item names and was previously filtered out.

Comment: oh mate!!!!! You just saved me!!!! Really I was knocking my head to the wall to find the solution you proposed, for a small project I am creating! amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use id in li elements, which will contain id of specific object in array.

```
//Created based off other variables
array = [{id: 1, title: "apple"}, {id: 2, title: "john"}, {id: 3, title: "monkey"}]; 

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var li=document.createElement('li');

    ul.appendChild(li);

    li.innerHTML += '<li>' + array[i].title;
    li.innerHTML += '<a href="#" id=' + array[i].id + ' class="clear">'+remove+'</a></li>';

}
$('a.clear').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    var index = $(this).attr('id');
    array = array.filter(function(item) {
        return item.id != index;
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Not sure that it will work - index is changed when element is removed from array. Try to remove 'apple' first, then something else....

Comment: @nevermind is right. This will not work as expected. You either have to use a key/value or search the array for the item you just clicked on and remove it (no duplicate items in the array if you do it this way)

Comment: Yes, sorry, my mistake. So, here is a good way to use an array of objects like this `array = [{id: 1, title: 'apple'}, {id: 2, title: 'john'}, {id: 3, title: 'monkey'}]`

Comment: And remove element like this: `array = array.filter(function(item) {item.id != index})`